# Is it possible to issue via Youtube API a search for particular set of videos without any ads?

Tags: javascript, api, youtube, ads

If I want to create(via Youtube API) a playlist of videos with cars as theme how to select those videos such that they do no have any ads?

Comment: You could pay for it i guess